# html errors i wasnt getting yesterday

Tags: node.js

I'm getting this error, it worked yesterday and I went to bed and woke up and now it dosent work with this error and when you go to localhost:8080 it shows the error. Any help?

```
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -4068,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var fs = require('fs');
//const e = require('./mongodb.js')
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  var q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  var filename = "." + q.pathname;
  fs.readFile(filename, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
      res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
      return res.end("404 Not Found");
    } 
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    return res.end();
  });
}).listen(8080);
console.log('8080')
```

Comment: Use `console.log(filename);` and check its content. It looks like `filename` points to a directory not to a file.

Comment: it directs to ./, how would i change that ? edit: fixed

Answer (score 0):

Use console.log(filename); and check its content. It looks like filename points to a directory not to a file. – pzaenger